# Extracting url parameter for a jetty component route

Tags: grails, apache-camel

I'm trying to build a proxy using the camel-jetty component in a Grails 2.0.3 application using the Routing plug-in.  I'm using the recipe from the Camel [cookbook](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html), but instead of hard-coding in a destination, I need to be able to change the destination using a parameter.  In other words, I want to call 
`http://localhost:8090/jetty/proxyToX?url=http://www.google.com`, 
and have it go to google.

The route I tried is (using simple):

```
from ( 'jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8090/jetty/proxyToX?matchOnUriPrefix=true' )
 .to( "jetty:${in.header.url}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false" )
```

However, this is giving me the following error:

ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'producerTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'camelContext' while setting bean property 'camelContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: in for class: JettyRoute

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

See this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanks Claus!  I'll try that when I get back to my machine (hopefully tomorrow).